# Commutative property of a finite group $G$

Tags: group-theory, commutative-algebra, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group where every two elements of  the same order commute.  Further suppose $x, y \in G$ such that $o(x) = d_1, o(y) = d_2$ and $xy = yx$, where $d_1 \neq d_2$. Then any two elements of order $d_1$ and $d_2$ are commute.

I know that this result is true because I can prove by using the result proved in an article published in the journal communication in algebra. But I want to solve it by another method.

In order to prove the claim, it is sufficient to prove that $xy' = y'x$ for any arbitrary element $y' \neq y \in G$ with $o(y') = d_2$. If $o(xy) = o(xy')$, then by given hypothesis, we get $xy xy' = xy' xy$ implies $xy' = y'x$. But I have stuck here how to prove $o(xy) = o(xy')?$

Thanks in advance for your kind help.

Comment: The strategy is not gonna work. Take $G=\mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z$, $x=-1, y=2, y'=4$, then $o(x+y)=o(1)=6$ but $o(x+y')=o(3)=2$.

Comment: yes, this will not work. I have to think another way.